# Cant retrieve data from db

Tags: php

I am trying connect mysql db and fetch some data.But echo command doesn't do anything.What am i doing wrong again ?why I am getting Undefined index: konu_baslik error

```
<?php

try{
    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog","root","");

}
catch (PDOException $ex){
$ex->getMessage();

}
$v=$db->prepare("select * from konular");

$v->execute(array());

$x=$v->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($x as $m){
echo  $m["konu_baslik"];
}

?>
```

Comment: Post your DB table as well

Comment: You can `var_dump()` your `$x` and check if there is something and also attach here.

Comment: Do some basic error-reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, then check your logs. And in case the database-connection failed, you don't actually do anything - you're not printing or logging the error, or have an indicator if it was successful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this work with you :

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username   = "root";
        $password   = "";
        $database  = "blog";
            try {
                    $db =new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                }

            $v=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM konular");
            $v->execute();

            if($v)
            {
                while($FetchData = $v->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    echo $FetchData['konu_baslik'].'\n';
                }
            }

            else
            {
                echo "Something went wrong";
            }

?>
```